# withRouter + connect + i18next not working together. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

[image: React-Redux Error]

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const { error } = state.Login;
    return { error };
}

export default compose(withRouter(withNamespaces()), connect(
    mapStateToProps,
))(ProfileMenu);
```

**It's not working with the i18next, without it yes, how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compose` is a functional method which composes functions with each other.

Try this:

```js
export default compose(withRouter(), withNamespaces(), connect(mapStateToProps))(ProfileMenu);
```